# Use Python's `timeit` from a program but functioning the same way as the command line?

Tags: python, timeit

For instance, [documentation says](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html):

> Note however that timeit will automatically determine the number of repetitions only when the command-line interface is used.

Is there a way to call it from within a Python script and have the number of repetitions be determined automatically, with only the shortest number returned?

Comment: Timeit now has an [`autorange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.autorange) function

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you call `timeit` from the command line like this:

```
python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.foo()'
```

The `timeit` module is called as a script. In particular, the `main` function is called:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

If you look at [the source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f1c6e7f86bbc/Lib/timeit.py#l220), you'll see that the `main` function can take an `args` argument:

```
def main(args=None):    
    if args is None:
        args = sys.argv[1:]
```

So indeed it is possible to run `timeit` from within a program with exactly the same behavior as you see when run from the CLI. Just supply your own `args` instead of allowing it to be set to `sys.argv[1:]`:

```
import timeit
import shlex

def foo():
    total = 0
    for i in range(10000):
        total += i**3
    return total

timeit.main(args=shlex.split("""-s'from __main__ import foo' 'foo()'"""))
```

will print something like

```
100 loops, best of 3: 7.9 msec per loop
```

---

Unfortunately, `main` prints to the console, instead of returning the time per loop. So if you want to programmatically use the result, perhaps the easiest way would be to start by copying [the `main` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f1c6e7f86bbc/Lib/timeit.py#l220) and then modifying it -- changing the printing code to instead return `usec`.

---

**Example by OP:** 
If you place this in `utils_timeit.py`:

```
import timeit
def timeit_auto(stmt="pass", setup="pass", repeat=3):
    """
    http://stackoverflow.com/q/19062202/190597 (endolith)
    Imitate default behavior when timeit is run as a script.

    Runs enough loops so that total execution time is greater than 0.2 sec,
    and then repeats that 3 times and keeps the lowest value.

    Returns the number of loops and the time for each loop in microseconds
    """
    t = timeit.Timer(stmt, setup)

    # determine number so that 0.2 <= total time < 2.0
    for i in range(1, 10):
        number = 10**i
        x = t.timeit(number) # seconds
        if x >= 0.2:
            break
    r = t.repeat(repeat, number)
    best = min(r)
    usec = best * 1e6 / number
    return number, usec
```

you can use it in scripts like this:

```
import timeit
import utils_timeit as UT

def foo():
    total = 0
    for i in range(10000):
        total += i**3
    return total

num, timing = UT.timeit_auto(setup='from __main__ import foo', stmt='foo()')
print(num, timing)
```

Comment: Yes, that looks good, except that it should not be this function's job to insert `os.curdir` into `sys.path`. Either PYTHONPATH should be properly set up, or it should be the job of the calling script (not this function) to fuss with `sys.path`.

Comment: Your example doesn't work for me (`ImportError: cannot import name foo`), but `UT.timeit_auto(lambda: foo())` does, producing similar output to IPython's `timeit foo()`.

Comment: @endolith: Oh but lambda adds some overhead, so not ideal.  `lambda: 5*5` is 86 ns while `5*5` is 21 ns.

Comment: @endolith: Are you calling the script from the command line? e.g. `python /path/to/script.py`?

Comment: No, I was using runfile() in Spyder to launch it.  You're right, if I run it on the command line it works.  Also, I just realized that IPython [has its own slightly different implementation](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/magics/execution.py#L982), which is why IPython will only do 1 loop for very slow functions, while the minimum with timeit.main() is 10 loops.

Comment: IDEs may mess with `__main__` which is probably why it does not work from Spyder. Multi-threaded and GUI programs can also have problems when run from within IDEs. Sometimes it appears to be necessary to run from the CLI.

Comment: I would like an approach where I dont have to define the setup for each problem. Is there someway to import everything from main?  I tried  setup='from __main__ import __all__'    and  setup = 'from __main__ import *'    but both dont work. Even better is ofcourse an approach were it is recognized what should be imported. 

E.g. if I have a dataframe and want to time df[variable_name].to_numpy()  I dont want to explicitly mention in the setup that df and variable_name have to be imported

Comment: Related topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68898318/custom-timeit-from-main-import-everything-necessary .

Answer (score 3):

As of Python 3.6, [`timeit.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer) objects have an [`autorange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.autorange) function that exposes how `number` is determined for command line execution.

Comment: Dear mad Physicist, could you maybe give an example of how to implement that in above timer? Also, do you maybe know the answer to the following question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68898318/custom-timeit-from-main-import-everything-necessary