# timeit for a specified period of time

Tags: python, timeit

I know I can use timeit like this:

```
timeit.timeit("f(x)", "from __main__ import f", number=100000)
```

And this will repeat `f()` 100000 times.

However, I'd like to do something like this:

```
timeit.timeit("f()", "from __main__ import f", duration=5000)
```

Which would repeat `f()` as much as necessary until it hits 5 seconds.

Is there something like this in **timeit** or would I have to craft a while-loop myself?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such option. Check out [this open issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue6422).

This is how it is done in `timeit.main`, which is called when you run something like `python -m timeit ...` (only including here the relevant part):

```
if number == 0:
    # determine number so that 0.2 <= total time < 2.0
    for i in range(1, 10):
        number = 10**i
        try:
            x = t.timeit(number)
        except:
            t.print_exc()
            return 1
        if verbose:
            print "%d loops -> %.*g secs" % (number, precision, x)
        if x >= 0.2:
            break
```

You can easily modify it to stop after some "total_time".

Answer (score 0):

When run from the command-line,

```
python -mtimeit -s'from script import f, x' 'f(x)'
```

the `timeit` script finds the number of iterations needed to call the function for at least 0.2 seconds. [Endolith has coalesced that code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19062202/190597) down to a function:

```
def timeit_auto(stmt="pass", setup="pass", repeat=3, duration=0.2):
    """
    https://stackoverflow.com/q/19062202/190597 (endolith)
    Imitate default behavior when timeit is run as a script.

    Runs enough loops so that total execution time is greater than 0.2 sec,
    and then repeats that 3 times and keeps the lowest value.

    Returns the number of loops and the time for each loop in microseconds
    """
    t = timeit.Timer(stmt, setup)

    # determine number so that 0.2 <= total time < 2.0
    for i in range(1, 10):
        number = 10 ** i
        x = t.timeit(number)  # seconds
        if x >= duration:
            break
    r = t.repeat(repeat, number)
    best = min(r)
    usec = best * 1e6 / number
    return number, usec
```

The [timeit code in the standard library](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a15bc8c12370/Lib/timeit.py#l282) can be found here.