# IPython %timeit magic - changing output from "mean & std" to "best of 3"

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, ipython, timeit

I am using an IPython 6.2.1 integration with Eclipse/PyDev on Ubuntu. Python version is 3.5.2.
I often see people timing a script like

```
>>>%timeit for _ in range(1000): True
10000 loops, best of 3: 37.8 µs per loop
```

When I perform the same operation, my output is

```
>>>%timeit for _ in range(1000): True
20.8 µs ± 353 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Imho, "best of 3" is the better measure, so I would like to change my output. 
I read both, the [IPython](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) and the [Python timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) documentation. They both don't even mention, that the output could differ from "best of 3". Is this a question of Linux/Eclipse/PyDev implementation or is there a way to change the output of the `timeit` module?

P.S.: The same happens in the Eclipse console, when I use `timeit`, so IPython is probably irrelevant here.

```
>>>timeit '"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))'
11 ns ± 0.0667 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000000 loops each)
```

Unutbu pointed out that you can achieve the desired behaviour from within a program. Running the [first script calling `timeit.main()` here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19062244/8881141) indeed returns the best of 3. But I would prefer a version that I can run interactively in the Eclipse console.

Comment: The `best of 3` is an older style of display.  It probably changed in some `ipython` release.  There could be a change in the `timeit` module, but I"m still using Py 3.5.

Comment: From `%timeit??` it appears that the display is generated by a `IPython.core.magics.execution.TimeitResult(loops, repeat, best, all_runs, compile_time, precision)` object.

Comment: I don't use Eclipse, but my guess it's using `ipython`, not `timeit` directly.

Answer (score 3):

The display is generated by a `TimeitResult` object (see the `timeit??` code listing).  With the -o option I get that object which I can examine:

```
In [95]: %timeit -o np.einsum('bdc,ac->ab', a, b, optimize=False)
170 µs ± 27.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
Out[95]: <TimeitResult : 170 µs ± 27.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)>
In [96]: res = _
In [97]: print(res)
170 µs ± 27.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [98]: vars(res)
Out[98]: 
{'_precision': 3,
 'all_runs': [1.6981208299985155,
  1.6976570829865523,
  1.6978941220149864,
  1.6976559630129486,
  1.6976608499826398,
  1.697147795028286,
  1.6977746890042908],
 'best': 0.0001697147795028286,
 'compile_time': 0.0,
 'loops': 10000,
 'repeat': 7,
 'timings': [0.00016981208299985155,
  0.00016976570829865524,
  0.00016978941220149863,
  0.00016976559630129485,
  0.00016976608499826398,
  0.0001697147795028286,
  0.0001697774689004291],
 'worst': 0.00016981208299985155}
```

It looks like the information to generate the `best of 3` display is still there, but the formatter is gone.  It might be found in an older version.

```
@property
def average(self):
    return math.fsum(self.timings) / len(self.timings)
```

Code is in `IPython/core/magics/execution.py`

Comment: Does this mean that newer versions abandoned the "best of 3" concept? I found [this thread on github from 2016](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/9984). Well, I can live with the new concept, though I think it is less accurate. It would be nice, if they included an option to choose, which information is displayed. You clearly demonstrated, that the information is there.

Comment: Someone has asked for the choice in display, https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10712

Answer (score 1):

This syntax std/mean/dev was added to IPython in 5 Oct 2016. See the issue #9984 https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/9984 about this improvement. And the implementation is here:

"Added mean + stdv to the %timeit magic - New tests pending - "

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/commit/509d8539c555ede6222d13cf1693388429213853#diff-ee52fbe4422737ccaa3d6d0b15ea5189

but syntax "best of 3" comes from python timeit module in main() function and this is generally the same in python2 and 3.