# custom timeit, from __main__ import everything necessary

Tags: python, timeit

The magic command `%timeit` is not made to be used in a script.

In [Use Python's `timeit` from a program but functioning the same way as the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062202/use-pythons-timeit-from-a-program-but-functioning-the-same-way-as-the-command), the following function was proposed by the user Unutbu:

```
import timeit

def timeit_auto(stmt="pass", setup="pass", repeat=3):
    """
    http://stackoverflow.com/q/19062202/190597 (endolith)
    Imitate default behavior when timeit is run as a script.

    Runs enough loops so that total execution time is greater than 0.2 sec,
    and then repeats that 3 times and keeps the lowest value.

    Returns the number of loops and the time for each loop in microseconds
    """
    t = timeit.Timer(stmt, setup)

    # determine number so that 0.2 <= total time < 2.0
    for i in range(1, 10):
        number = 10**i
        x = t.timeit(number) # seconds
        if x >= 0.2:
            break
    r = t.repeat(repeat, number)
    best = min(r)
    usec = best * 1e6 / number
    return number, usec
```

Which can be used as follows:

```
import timeit
import utils_timeit as UT

def foo():
    total = 0
    for i in range(10000):
        total += i**3
    return total

num, timing = UT.timeit_auto(setup='from __main__ import foo', stmt='foo()')
print(num, timing)
```

Which is a very smart and handy solution. However, I am looking for a even better way. I don't want to give a `setup` statement to the function, I think it is very obnoxious. If I have a dataframe `df` and a column name `column_name_a`, I don't want to have to explicitly state `setup='from __main__ import df, column_name_a'` whenever I want to time an operation to `df[column_name_a]`.

Is there a nice way to fix it? I did it myself by adding this to the function, such that all the variables that are required are added to the setup statement in a loop by catching errors:

```
condition = True

setup = 'from __main__ import _'

while condition:
    try:
        t = timeit.Timer(stmt, setup)
        t.repeat(repeat, number)
        condition = False
    except NameError as err:
        str_err = str(err)
        extra_import = str_err.split(sep="'")[1]
        setup = setup + ', ' + extra_import
```

this is ofcourse not a very subtle solution. Does anyone have a better approach?

Furthermore, in the same thread ([Use Python's `timeit` from a program but functioning the same way as the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062202/use-pythons-timeit-from-a-program-but-functioning-the-same-way-as-the-command)), someone proposed to use the `Timer.autorange` method. I am not sure how to include this in the function. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

[`timeit.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer) objects have accepted a `globals` paramter since python 3.5, which allows you to use your module namespace directly. The [`autorange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.autorange) method was added in python 3.6, and is the official version of [Untubu's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19062244/2988730).

Here is how you can put it all together:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> def foo(): ...
>>> num, timing = Timer(stmt='foo()', globals=globals()).autorange()
```

You can use `timeit.Timer` objects directly for this exact application as of python 3.6. If you have version 3.5, you can modify Untubu's solution as follows:

```
def timeit_auto(stmt="pass", setup="pass", repeat=3, globals=None):
    t = timeit.Timer(stmt, setup, globals=globals())
    ...
```